# Please list the Pasukim Chumash that contain 29 letters. if so please state Chapter and verse

Tags: pentateuch-chumash

Please list the Pasukim in the Chumash that contain 29 letters, ideally  state Chapter and verse. For context, I am buying Pasukim in a Sefer Torah that contain 29 Letters.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.8.12?lang=bi

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Michael and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us! Not sure this question is fully in scope but hopefully there are plenty of others you might want to ask.

Answer (score 8):

There are **69 pesukim** in the Chumash that fit the bill, so 29 is a fairly common letter total for pesukim.  *(The high-scorer in the Chumash is a 50 letter total at 134 pesukim)*

For 29, the very first is:

> (בראשית ה:יב) וַיְחִי קֵינָן שִׁבְעִים שָׁנָה וַיּוֹלֶד אֶת מַהֲלַלְאֵל

and the very last is:

> (דברים לב:מח) וַיְדַבֵּר ה' אֶל מֹשֶׁה בְּעֶצֶם הַיּוֹם הַזֶּה לֵאמֹר

**The full list can be accessed [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e6VIUmSXGUgHxBKwBeCf7IoVu9FZ0gfH/view?usp=sharing).**

Comment: How did you get this?

Comment: I got it from (my very own) basehasefer.com where one can search for pesukim by a whole bunch of statistical parameters. In this case, select Torah from the seforim check boxes in the settings panel on the right; then use the Pasuk Settings tab of the Advanced Search to restrict pasuk length to a range of 29 to 29 letters; then click the search button.  For a screen shot of how to do this see: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TcsTiyGDdDMvzyoYnsyYbp1BIcNb6tU9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What a great technical skills!

Comment: Kouty,  Amazing  I am trying to duplicate your findings, but am unable to follow your steps as you outlined.  In the meantime, I would appreciate the 69 listings either palced in the comments or sent to my email   crystalsilhouettes AT gmail   Todah Michoel Aryeh

Comment: Michoel Aryeh - I just edited a link to the full 69 pasuk list at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: I GOT IT I followed all of your steps and arrived at the 69 results

Comment: Great! בהצלחה!!!